# Using Variables within the Base Constructor C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have this class and constructor

```
public class BillOutcomeClass
{
    public string LargeMessage { get; set; }
    public string MobileMessage { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public BillOutcomeClass(string acctNumber, HttpContext currentContext)
    {
        Customer customer = CustomerSecurity.GetCustomer(currentContext);
        Account acct = customer.GetAccountForTransaction(acctNumber);
    }
}
```

I need to be able to use the `Account` and `Customer` instance within the PastDue Class. It is imperative to be able to access these Classes within the inherited class.

Here is the inherited class.

```
public class PastDue : BillOutcomeClass
{
    public PastDue (string acctNumber, HttpContext currentContext) : base (acctNumber,  currentContext)
    {
        /// I need to be able to access customer.prop, and acct.prop from the base class
    }
}
```

Comment: Save them in a protected class variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to me you just need some `protected` properties:

```
public class BillOutcomeClass
{
    public string LargeMessage { get; set; }
    public string MobileMessage { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    protected Customer Cust { get; set; }
    protected Account Acct { get; set; }

    public BillOutcomeClass(string acctNumber, HttpContext currentContext)
    {
        this.Cust = CustomerSecurity.GetCustomer(currentContext);
        this.Acct = customer.GetAccountForTransaction(acctNumber);
    }
}
```